# Separate part of a string

Tags: php, variables

I'm having trouble getting a part of a

```
a:10:{i:0;s:4:"8997";i:1;s:4:"8966";i:2;s:4:"8955";i:3;s:4:"8951";i:4;s:4:"8956";i:5;s:4:"8954";i:6;s:4:"8959";i:7;s:4:"8960";i:8;s:4:"8961";i:9;s:4:"8962";}
```

I need to separate the number 10 at the beginning of this string. It's just an example and it could be a number like 1,10,100.
So I need to separate it between "a:" and the following ":"

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Comment: Thank worked. Thanks!